# python syntax error with nonexistent line

Tags: python, syntax-error

I wrote this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
alarm = False
firealarm = False
fc = 0
fire = False
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
try:
           print("hi")
           time.sleep(2)
           print("5")
           while True:
                         if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
                                    print ("ALARM TRIPPED.finding alarm nat$
                                    fire = true
                                    alarm = True
                         time.sleep(1)
                        while fire:
                           if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN) == False:
                                firealarm = True
                                fire = False
                           fc = fc+1
                           if fc == 5:
                                fire = false
                           time.sleep(0.5)
                         while alarm:
                          if firealarm:
                            print("alar was fire evacuate now!")
```

and I get this on a raspberry pi

```
File "emailalarm1.py", line 32
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please give some valid code

Comment: The indentation is all over the place.  You need to fix it up before anyone can tell what's going on.

Comment: You are missing an except: in the try: block

Comment: 32 is a blank line @drwatson

Comment: Your code is **full** of errors. The error at the end is merely because Python never found the end of an expression started on an earlier line. You are missing a closing `)`, `]` or `}` somewhere, most likely.

Comment: @DrWatson: that is perfectly plausible. It means that by the time Python got to the last (empty line) there was still an unfinished expression left.

Comment: if this is an exact copy/paste of your code, you have an unclosed quote + unclosed parenthesis at `print ("ALARM TRIPPED.finding alarm nat$`

Comment: thank you, it was missing
except:
    print "This is an error message!"

Comment: @MatToufoutu: that looks like a terminal or console artifact; the line  is truncated at the right-hand side of the screen, the `$` indicating that you need to scroll to the right.

Comment: Your code will not run because of 1, wrong indentation; 2, miss match brackets; 3, try block without exception

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated your indentation is awful -- but the root cause of this error could well be that this line is missing both a closing quote, and a closing bracket

```
print ("ALARM TRIPPED.finding alarm nat$
```

This may well mean that Python will be trying to interpret the rest of the code as part of that print call, and so it fails on the last line.

Comment: That looks like a terminal or console artifact; the line  is truncated at the right-hand side of the screen, the `$` indicating that you need to scroll to the right.

Comment: Ah possible Martijn - the rest of the code is such a mess it is difficult to tell :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have forgotten the **except** block. You should have some thing like that:

```
try:
    # Some treatement
    ...
except Exception as e:
    # Treat exception
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Also for print function you should use triple quote (""") https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings